# Spring Social Security error

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-google

I'm using Spring Social Security in XML notation to authenticate users into my website with Google and Facebook.

Everything works fine but after a couple of hours it stops working and users can't authenticate using the social login. I don't know why the **`GET`** request to (Google example) https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me give me a `400` bad request and redirect users to `/signin` instead of my `redirect_uri`.

**If I restart my Tomcat server, social login authentication works again during another couple of hours.** Now I have configured a crontab for restating my server every hour, but I don't think it's a good solution.

I have two supossals:

1) The problem is something related to an expired token and I should handle the Exception and reauthenticate throw the ConnectController flow. But I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

2) The problem is something related to my `inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository` that clears when I `restart` the server and works again.

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<beans:import resource="spring-web-servlet.xml" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
    <authentication-provider ref="socialAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- social login filter which is a pre authentication filter and works 
    for /auth service url -->
<beans:bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" name="socialAuthenticationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authManager"
        ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="userIdSource" ref="userIdSource" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="usersConnectionRepository"
        ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="authServiceLocator"
        ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        ref="successHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="successHandler" class="com.ejemplo.social.AppSuccessHandler" />

<beans:bean id="failureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    id="SecurityAuthFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        ref="successHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
        ref="failureHandler" />
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />

    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/?iniciar" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/dentro" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/?error" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <csrf disabled="true" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/inicio" access="permitAll" />

    <form-login login-page="/?iniciar" default-target-url="/exist-usuario"
        authentication-failure-url="/?error" username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" />

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/?logout"
        invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID, TOKEN_KEY" />

    <remember-me user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"
        key="TOKEN_KEY" />

    <headers disabled="true" />

    <!-- Adds social authentication filter to the Spring Security filter chain. -->
    <custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" />
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="SecurityAuthFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="key" value="TOKEN_KEY" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="userDetailsService"
        ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="30000"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="parameter" value="remember-me" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"
    class="com.ejemplo.security.CustomUserDetailsService">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customSocialUserDetailsService"
    class="com.ejemplo.social.CustomSocialUserDetailsService" />

<beans:bean id="userIdSource"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource" />

<beans:bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="customSocialUserDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- inmemory connection repository which holds connection repository per 
    local user -->
<beans:bean id="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.mem.InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="connectionFactoryLocator"
        ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="connectionSignUp" ref="connectionSignUp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- If no local user is associated to a social connection then connection 
    sign up will create a new local user and map it to social user -->
<beans:bean id="connectionSignUp" class="com.ejemplo.social.AppConnectionSignUp" />

<!-- service registry will holds connection factory of each social provider -->
<beans:bean id="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"
    class="com.ejemplo.social.AppSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="facebookAuthenticationService" />
            <!-- <beans:ref bean="twitterAuthenticationService" /> -->
            <beans:ref bean="googleAuthenticationService" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="facebookAuthenticationService"
    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="apiKey"
        value="${app.config.oauth.facebook.apikey}" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="appSecret"
        value="${app.config.oauth.facebook.apisecret}" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="googleAuthenticationService"
    class="org.springframework.social.google.security.GoogleAuthenticationService">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="apiKey"
        value="${app.config.oauth.google.apikey}" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="appSecret"
        value="${app.config.oauth.google.apisecret}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

<!-- Enable the annotations for defining the secure role -->
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</global-method-security>
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.social.version>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring.social.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
</properties>
```

**menu.jsp**

```
    <h4>Iniciar sesión con:</h4>
<a href="<c:url value='../auth/facebook?scope=email' />"
    rel="nofollow"
    class="btn-facebook"> <i
    class="zmdi zmdi-facebook"></i> Facebook
</a> <a href="<c:url value='../auth/google?scope=email' />"
    rel="nofollow" class="btn-google">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-google"></i> Google
</a>
```

**application.properties**

```
app.config.oauth.facebook.apikey=******
app.config.oauth.facebook.apisecret=******
app.config.oauth.twitter.apikey=******
app.config.oauth.twitter.apisecret=******
app.config.oauth.google.apikey=******
app.config.oauth.google.apisecret=******
```

**Logs**

```
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,713 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?scope=email at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,713 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?scope=email at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,713 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?scope=email at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,713 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?scope=email at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,713 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,714 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationRedirectException: 
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,714 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,714 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFailureHandler@22ad613b
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?state=63c3ac35-e0f3-46b7-9887-d8932c6b0034&code=4/AADVb20K49mFatQ8hDxLtqLlvz8LSsD4IHB2ciufaR46gzPrJr1RUoJmw1QM_Zb4pc7ruZ9snU1-IdOg2SnGu34 at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?state=63c3ac35-e0f3-46b7-9887-d8932c6b0034&code=4/AADVb20K49mFatQ8hDxLtqLlvz8LSsD4IHB2ciufaR46gzPrJr1RUoJmw1QM_Zb4pc7ruZ9snU1-IdOg2SnGu34 at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?state=63c3ac35-e0f3-46b7-9887-d8932c6b0034&code=4/AADVb20K49mFatQ8hDxLtqLlvz8LSsD4IHB2ciufaR46gzPrJr1RUoJmw1QM_Zb4pc7ruZ9snU1-IdOg2SnGu34 at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /auth/google?state=63c3ac35-e0f3-46b7-9887-d8932c6b0034&code=4/AADVb20K49mFatQ8hDxLtqLlvz8LSsD4IHB2ciufaR46gzPrJr1RUoJmw1QM_Zb4pc7ruZ9snU1-IdOg2SnGu34 at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Request is to process authentication
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - Created POST request for "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - Setting request Accept header to [application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/json, application/+json]
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,909 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - Writing [{client_id=[**********.apps.googleusercontent.com], client_secret=[************], code=[4/AADVb20K49mFatQ8hDxLtqLlvz8LSsD4IHB2ciufaR46gzPrJr1RUoJmw1QM_Zb4pc7ruZ9snU1-IdOg2SnGu34], redirect_uri=[https://ejemplo.com/auth/google], grant_type=[authorization_code]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" using [org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter@45fbaee9]
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,980 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - POST request for "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" resulted in 200 (OK)
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,980 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - Reading [interface java.util.Map] as "application/json;charset=utf-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4e445436]
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,984 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - Created GET request for "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,988 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,989 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.google.security.GoogleAuthenticationService  - failed to exchange for access
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me": Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Petición incorrecta"; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Petición incorrecta"
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.social.google.api.impl.AbstractGoogleApiOperations.getEntity(AbstractGoogleApiOperations.java:50)
    at org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.impl.PlusTemplate.getPerson(PlusTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.impl.PlusTemplate.getGoogleProfile(PlusTemplate.java:110)
    at org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleAdapter.fetchUserProfile(GoogleAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleAdapter.fetchUserProfile(GoogleAdapter.java:31)
    at org.springframework.social.google.connect.GoogleConnectionFactory.extractProviderUserId(GoogleConnectionFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.social.security.provider.OAuth2AuthenticationService.getAuthToken(OAuth2AuthenticationService.java:100)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthService(SocialAuthenticationFilter.java:266)
    at org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(SocialAuthenticationFilter.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 400 Petición incorrecta"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2142)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2RequestInterceptor.intercept(OAuth2RequestInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619)
    ... 55 more
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,989 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: authentication failed
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,989 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain null Authentication
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:52,989 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter  - Delegating to authentication failure handler org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFailureHandler@22ad613b
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SocialAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,048 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,049 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,049 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,049 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,049 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG   2018-02-18 23:37:53,049 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-3] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy  - /signin reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
```

Thank you very much for the help!